# OS X + Vim: Open Finder for a Folder in NerdTree (Vim)

Tags: macos, vim, nerdtree

I use the [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) plugin for MacVim religiously, and find myself often wanting to open a folder in the Finder to work with the files. An example would be wanting to preview and copy some images.

Is there a quick way to do this that doesn't involve changing the current directory? My perfect scenario would be:

- Move cursor to desired folder
- Press "some key"
- Folder opens up in the finder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is available out-of-the-box with NERDTree now as part of the [fs_menu.vim](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim) plugin. In fact, this feature only works on the Mac:

```
if has("gui_mac") || has("gui_macvim") || has("mac")
    call NERDTreeAddMenuItem({'text': '(r)eveal in Finder the current node', 'shortcut': 'r', 'callback': 'NERDTreeRevealInFinder'})
    call NERDTreeAddMenuItem({'text': '(o)pen the current node with system editor', 'shortcut': 'o', 'callback': 'NERDTreeExecuteFile'})
    call NERDTreeAddMenuItem({'text': '(q)uicklook the current node', 'shortcut': 'q', 'callback': 'NERDTreeQuickLook'})
endif
```

Navigate to a node in the NERDTree view, type `m` to bring up the fs menu, then `o` to open the current node. Directories will be opened in a new Finder window, files will be opened in the application you have set as the default editor for the file's type.

This is accomplished compliments of the [open](http://ss64.com/osx/open.html) command:

```
function! NERDTreeExecuteFile()
    let treenode = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected()
    if treenode != {}
        call system("open '" . treenode.path.str() . "'")
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for following up after so long. Just tried it out and works perfectly! : )

Answer (score 1):

The shell command to open a folder is

```
$ open /path/to/folder
```

In a Vim function, this command could be invoked like this:

```
let g:mypath = /path/to/folder
execute "silent !open " . g:mypath
```

NERDTree's documentation has [a simple and easy to follow example](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L35):

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
       \ 'key': 'foo',
       \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeCDHandler',
       \ 'quickhelpText': 'echo full path of current node',
       \ 'scope': 'DirNode' })

function! NERDTreeCDHandler(dirnode)
    call a:dirnode.changeToDir()
endfunction
```

that you can expand using [the global objects listed a few lines above](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L34):

```
g:NERDTreePath
g:NERDTreeDirNode
g:NERDTreeFileNode
g:NERDTreeBookmark
```

Comment: Pretty sure your links to the documentation are out of date.

Comment: @Ben, that kind of thing could happen, yes. Links fixed.

Comment: @romainl it happened again! maybe link to an specific commit

Comment: @kroe, fixed again, hopefully for good this time.